# Server Linux DNS

Tags: linux, server

I don't how dns works. Please explain if some knows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good description --> [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-resolv.howdnsworks.html)

Comment: I installed Zpanel. I installed it on my VPS Server where I run CentOS 6.7. I have also installed on it VNC and Mozilla. Ok so I logged in to my zpanel using VNC and mozilla, and then I created a domain. I waited 5 minutes and after it was live. I created it 10 minutes ago. It works but just on VPS.. for instance if I want to acces it from my PC it doesn't work. Can someone explain me why and how can I solve this problem? Or maybe I have to wait a while until it will be processed also in "my internet"?? (I don't know how to explain this, I'm a beginner) I hope that you understand me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between DNS-server that serves request for your domains and **caching** DNS-server, which collects global DNS-records.

Comment: I installed Zpanel. I installed it on my VPS Server where I run CentOS 6.7. I have also installed on it VNC and Mozilla. Ok so I logged in to my zpanel using VNC and mozilla, and then I created a domain. I waited 5 minutes and after it was live. I created it 10 minutes ago. It works but just on VPS.. for instance if I want to acces it from my PC it doesn't work. Can someone explain me why and how can I solve this problem? Or maybe I have to wait a while until it will be processed also in "my internet"?? (I don't know how to explain this, I'm a beginner) I hope that you understand me. Thanks.